# QAudioDeviceInfo finds no default audio device on Android

Tags: android, qt, c++11, qtquick2, qtmultimedia

I have created a simple player application using QAudioOutput. it is working fine.

Later i moved player code to separate project and built it as shared library and creating player object in my application.

But QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput)) returning empty list

i have verified deployment package. it has multimedia dependencies

Code:

```
QAudioFormat audioFormat;
audioFormat.setSampleRate(44100);
audioFormat.setChannelCount(2);
audioFormat.setSampleSize(16);
audioFormat.setCodec("audio/pcm");
audioFormat.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
audioFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
if (!info.isFormatSupported(audioFormat))
{
    throw myexception("Can not play audio due to unsupported format");
}
```

Then i have created one more shared library it have a simple class inside the constructor i calling above code its working but when i include complete code it is not working

what might be the reason

settings:

qt5.5

andriod ndk12